# Creating local modules using cdktf

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create a Terraform module in CDKTF following the documentation at [https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/modules](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cdktf/concepts/modules.)

I created the module as shown in the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from constructs import Construct
from cdktf import App, TerraformStack, TerraformOutput
from imports.aws.provider import AwsProvider
from imports.aws.s3_bucket import S3Bucket

class MyStack(TerraformStack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str):
        super().__init__(scope, id)

        AwsProvider(self, "AWS", region="eu-west-1", profile="<MY-PROFILE>")

        bucket_name = '<MY-BUCKET-NAME>'
        # define resources here
        s3_bucket = S3Bucket(
            self, 'testBucket',
            bucket=bucket_name
        )

        TerraformOutput(self, "my_output", value=s3_bucket.arn)

app = App()
MyStack(app, "s3_module")

app.synth()
```

Then, I created another folder for the main stack and added the module in the 'cdktf.json' file

```
{
  "language": "python",
  "app": "pipenv run python main.py",
  "projectId": "e2b44a02-65b2-42de-ab52-3863d211c94c",
  "sendCrashReports": "true",
  "terraformProviders": [
  "hashicorp/aws@~>4.0"
  ],
  "terraformModules": [{
     "name": "s3_module",
     "source": "../s3_module"
  }],
 "codeMakerOutput": "imports",
 "context": {
    "excludeStackIdFromLogicalIds": "true",
    "allowSepCharsInLogicalIds": "true"
  }
}
```

I also called the module in main.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from constructs import Construct 
from cdktf import App, TerraformStack
from imports.s3_module import S3Module
from imports.aws.provider import AwsProvider

class MyStack(TerraformStack):
    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, id: str):
        super().__init__(scope, id)

        AwsProvider(self, "AWS", region="eu-west-1", profile="<MY-PROFILE>")

        # define resources here
        my_module = S3Module(self, 's3_module')
    

app = App()
MyStack(app, "service_v2")

app.synth()
```

However, when I  run "cdktf deploy", Terraform does not add any resources:
[image: cdktf terminal output]

Can you help me understand where the error is? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that the `terraformModules` field in the `cdktf.json` file is for communicating which **Terraform modules** you want to use, i.e. directories that contain `.tf` files.

This is what allows the `cdktf get` command to know which Python bindings you need so that it can generate them into your `imports/` directory. Enabling the import statements to work.

If instead you would like to factor out parts of your infrastructure configuration into separate **Python modules**, you could adapt a strategy where you subclass from `Construct`, as follows:

### Example module: `s3_bucket.py`:

```
import constructs
import cdktf
from imports.aws.provider import AwsProvider
from imports.aws.s3_bucket import (
    S3Bucket
)

class S3BucketInfra(constructs.Construct):

    def __init__(self, scope: constructs.Construct,
                        construct_id: str,
                        bucket_name: str,
                        provider: AwsProvider):
        super().__init__(scope=scope, id=construct_id)
        self.bucket = S3Bucket( self,
                                'bucket',
                                bucket=bucket_name,
                                force_destroy=False,
                                provider=provider  )
```

### Example main module: `main.py`:

```
import constructs
import cdktf
from s3_bucket import (
    S3BucketInfra
)

class SomeExampleStack(cdktf.TerraformStack):

    def __init__(self, scope: constructs.Construct, construct_id: str):
        super().__init__(scope=scope, id=construct_id)
        self.some_bucket = S3BucketInfra(   scope=self,
                                            construct_id='some-bucket',
                                            bucket_name='testBucket',
                                            provider=AwsProvider(self, "AWS", region="eu-west-1", profile="<MY-PROFILE>")  )


app = cdktf.App()
SomeExampleStack(scope=app, construct_id="service_v2")
app.synth()
```

I am pretty new to CDKTF myself and the documentation is a little thin, but this is what worked for me :)

Comment: This solution also works for me :) . But then how can I use the modules stored in the repository (Bitbucket or GitHub)?
I would like to rewrite an application and translate all the terraform files (the init command calls all the modules with a specific tag).
Do I necessarily have to create a library to be installed via pipenv? Thank you :)

Comment: By "modules stored in the repository" do you mean normal Terraform ones ?  i.e.  .tf files ?

Comment: Exactly. I have .tf files in the repository

Comment: Can you specify a `source` value in a form like `git@github.com:hashicorp/example.git` for entries of `"terraformModules"` ?

Comment: Yes, I use those modules for all my deployments, changing versions as I make updates 
(git@github.com:hashicorp/example.git //services/aws-module/etl?ref=vx.x.x). If I put this url into cdktf.json it should work (I hope).
But I would like to align the whole code by writing everything in CDKTF.

Comment: Makes sense. I would just go through those .tf modules and re-write them to be Python modules instead.  Each would then provide a class that extends from `constructs.Construct` that you can re-use from elsewhere.

Those modules could exist as self-contained Python packages, e.g. on your own PyPi, or just bring into your main repository

Comment: I have understood. I will now try to go this route by directly building an installable PyPi package. 
Thank you, "you gave me hope" :D